# Custom js builder for ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

We are using ExtJs 3.4. I would like to build a trimmed version of ext-all.js so that the file size will be reduced. Is there any automated way to build this custom file or should I manually dig into the file and search for dependencies.

We have a page that use the following components.

1. Tab Panel
2. Panel
3. XTemplate
4. Radio Group
5. Button

And we use 'view port' to render the components. Can any one suggest how can we achieve this?

Even before that, given our case where we use these components, is it advisable to go for this customization ?

Comment: In extjs 4 package there is `jsbuilder` attached. This tool can build ext from sources using jsb file as input. You can modify jsb file and try to build release, but I'm not sure if it'll work with ext 3.4

Answer (score 1):

See [http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorial:Building_Ext_From_Source](http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorial%3aBuilding_Ext_From_Source)